# Are the Monster Lore paragraphs from the printed manuals available online?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, dnd-insider

I got a subscription for DD Insider and have been especially satisfied with the online compendium: being able to quickly open the relevant monster entries in seperate tabs during an encounter has definitely shortened preparation time.

One thing I miss, however, are the Lore entries that were in the printed Monster Manuals/Vaults, of which I have a few. So far I have been unable to find them anywhere in the compendium.

Has WotC just not made these bits of information available online, or have I been looking in all the wrong places?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, they are not all available online.

Although the DDI Compendium (and by extension, the Builder) tends to have some or all of the flavor for player mechanics, the DDI services are otherwise solely concerned with providing access to the mechanics of the game. Leaves a reason for you to still buy the books.

However! Some of the Compendium's material is taken from the *Dungeon* and *Dragon* Magazines rather than the published books, and the magazines are available in a (semi-searchable) database for pdf download in full or by article, so **some** lore is available to you through the DDI in that manner.